# Compound Validation annotations

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, hibernate-validator

I would like the group some annotation in one and then need that the annotations work fine with Hibernate-validator and the generate-ddl utily of Hibernate

I have a bunch of entities and most of then had similar fields. For example:

```
@Entity 
public class Usuario implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "CODIGO", nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private Integer code;

    @Column(name = "NOMBRE", length = 75, nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 75)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "CLAVE", length = 75, nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 75)
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "ES_ADMINISTRADOR")
    @NotNull
    @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.NumericBooleanType")
    private Boolean isAdmin;

    [...]
}
```

And I want have something like this other

```
@Entity 
public class Usuario implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @CodeField
    private Integer code;

    @Column(name = "NOMBRE")
    @NameField
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "CLAVE", length = 75, nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 75)
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "ES_ADMINISTRADOR")
    @BooleanField
    private Boolean isAdmin;

    [...]
}
```

Can I do that?

Comment: You want to combine JPA schema markup and JSR-303 validations into a single annotation...?  No there is not canned support for that :(

Comment: @Affe Yes I afraid that but I hope there are some way for doing something similar in Hibernate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not possible. The composition feature of Bean Validation only allows to aggregate several constraint annotations into a new higher-level constraint, but this does not take any JPA annotations into account.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you want to achieve, but as far as it comes to Hibernate Validator, it is possible to create your own constraints through implementing *ConstraintValidator* interface.

I suggest you to read the manual, it's fairly easy:
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en/html/validator-customconstraints.html